# Como copiar para área de transferência simultaneamente valores de vários elementos <span> com JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Para copiar o valor de um elemento span cujo ID é igual a "nome", após clicar em um button, eu estou fazendo assim, por exemplo:

```
        function copiar() {                        
        const element = document.getElementById('nome');
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(element);
        window.getSelection().addRange(range);
        document.execCommand("copy");               
        }
```

Porém, tenho outro span cujo ID é igual a "sobrenome" e gostaria de copiar simultaneamente ao clicar no button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ## AVISO:
>
> #### Até a data, 31/12/2019, em que foi escrita essa resposta essa solução somente é compatível com os navegadores baseados no [Chromium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser)), Firefox e Opera. A resposta é baseada em tecnologia considerada até o momento recente e ainda não foi totalmente implementa entre os navegadores.
>
> [W3C | Clipboard API and events](https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#async-clipboard-api)
>
> [Can I Use | Clipboard API: writeText](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_clipboard_writetext)
>
> [Webkit API Improvements | Clipboard API Improvements](https://webkit.org/blog/8170/clipboard-api-improvements/)

---

Uma alternativa seria utilizar a [API da Area de transferência](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) para fazer a cópia das informações.

Sua documentação a descreve:

> A **API da área de transferência** fornece a capacidade de responder aos
>   comandos da área de transferência (recortar, copiar e colar), além de
>   ler e gravar de forma assíncrona na área de transferência do sistema.
>
> Esta API foi projetada para substituir o acesso à área de
>   transferência usando `document.execCommand()`.

Essa API adiciona a interface [`Navigator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator) a propriedade de leitura [`clipboard`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/clipboard)  que retorna o objeto [`Clipboard`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard) usado para ler e gravar o conteúdo na área de transferência.

Lembrando que:

> O acesso ao conteúdo da área de transferência é bloqueado por trás da
>   [API de permissões](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API) ; sem permissão do usuário, não é permitido ler ou
>   alterar o conteúdo na área de transferência.

Para gravar uma string na area de transferência usa-se o método [`writeText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText)

```js
function copiar() {

  let nome = document.getElementById('Nome').innerText;
  let sobrenome = document.getElementById('Sobrenome').innerText;

  navigator.clipboard.writeText(nome + " " + sobrenome)
    .then(
      function() {
        console.log(" Os dados foram copiados.")
      },
      function() {
        console.error("Houve um problema ao copiar os dados.")
      });
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Nome:</label>
  <span id="Nome">Augusto</span>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Sobrenome:</label>
  <span id="Sobrenome">Vasques</span>
</div>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="copiar()" value="Copiar">
```

Comment: muito obrigado pela resposta. E, depois de muito pesquisar, a solução abaixo também parece viável, pois seleciona o texto copiado, indicando visualmente ao usuário os dados copiados. É interessante..

Answer (score 0):

Esta alternativa:

```js
function copiar() {
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges(range);
        const element = document.querySelectorAll(".nomesobrenome");
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.setStartBefore(element[0]);
        range.setEndAfter(element[1]);
        const selection = window.getSelection();
        window.getSelection().addRange(range);
        document.execCommand("copy");
    }
```

```html
     <div>
      <label>Nome:</label>
      <span id="Nome" class="nomesobrenome">Augusto</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Sobrenome:</label>
      <span id="Sobrenome" class="nomesobrenome">Vasques</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="button" onclick="copiar()" value="Copiar">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function copiarSPAN() {
    const span = document.querySelectorAll('span');
    const range = new Range();
    range.setStartBefore(span[1]);
    range.setEndAfter(span[2]);
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("copy");
}
```